# How to group learnable parameters for tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I usually structure my learnable parameters in the following way in tensorflow:

```
learnable_weights = {
  'w1': tf.get_variable(...),
  ...
  'wn': tf.get_variable(...),
} 

learnable_biases = {
  'bc1': tf.get_variable(...),
  ...
  'bd3': tf.get_variable(...)
}
```

The problem I started to recently encounter is the congested tensorboard graph, where I have a lot of weights in the auxilary nodes (this is a part of a big graph, and the number of these nodes is way bigger):

[image]

I tried to group them with `tf.name_scope`. Something like this:

```
with tf.name_scope('learnable_params'):
  learnable_weights = {...}
  learnable_biases = {...}
```

But this has no effect on the graph in tensorboard.

Any reason why or better any suggestions how to group the learnable parameters so that they will not clutter the tensorboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `variable_scope` instead of `name_scope`. AFAIK variables created via `get_variable` ignore `name_scope`, and I wouldn't be surprised if this applies to the graph organization in Tensorboard as well. I only use `variable_scope` to wrap anything that creates variables and I've never had these issues with "unorganized" variables.